# Why Would This C++ Code Deadlock or Freeze?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, atomic

I have what I think is a simple background worker thread setup that has been working for millions of executions over many days. Recently I got a hang at this point in my code and am wondering if I've missed something in my setup that led to a deadlock.

Code snippet (will not compile):

```
cout << "Starting." << endl;
atomic<bool> keepThreadRunning;
mutex coutMutex; 
keepThreadRunning = true;
auto doBackgroundTask1 = [&keepThreadRunning, &backgroundData1, &coutMutex] () {
    size_t numSteps = 0;
    while (keepThreadRunning && backgroundData1->doOneTask()) { 
        ++numSteps;
    }
    coutMutex.lock();
        cout << " Did " << numSteps << " background 1 tasks." << endl;
    coutMutex.unlock();
};
auto doBackgroundTask2 = [&keepThreadRunning, &backgroundData2, &coutMutex] () {
    size_t numSteps = 0;
    while (keepThreadRunning && backgroundData2->doOneTask()) { 
        ++numSteps;
    }
    coutMutex.lock();
        cout << " Did " << numSteps << " background 2 tasks." << endl;
    coutMutex.unlock();
};
thread backgroundThread1(doBackgroundTask1);
thread backgroundThread2(doBackgroundTask2);
doForegroundWork();
keepThreadRunning = false;
backgroundThread1.join();
backgroundThread2.join();
cout << "Finished." << endl;
```

I suspect I'm doing something wrong with the atomic or the mutex. I have no way of proving this to you, but the two sets of background data and the foreground work are completely isolated, so the threads have no buried locks or conflicts over that data. I'm showing two threads just in case I've missed something with the mutex around cout.

Comment: Maybe not an issue now, but if the `cout` call throws an exception for some reason, the `mutex` remains locked.  Use `std::lock_guard`.

Comment: You will probably have to use a debugger and debug your code. Other than the  unlikely chance that `cout` throws and exception the bug is not in the code that is shown.

Comment: For what it's worth, I don't see anything wrong in the code shown. The problem is likely somewhere in the code not shown, perhaps inside `doOneTask` or `doForegroundWork`

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).